# Shorter way to constraint a function

Tags: f#, type-constraints

I'm looking for a shorter way (if there is one) to constraint a function. E.g.

```
let inline sincos (a:'T) =
    let y = sin a
    let x = cos a
    y, x
```

For using this function, 'T will need to support both `Sin` and `Cos` static members.
I can constraint it to work on float32 with:

```
let sincosf = sincos : float32 -> float32 -> float32
```

or using some wildcard:

```
let sincosf = sincos : float32 -> _
```

My question is, would it be possible to add a type parameter to `sincos` so I just have to write:

```
let sincosf = sincos<float32>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `let sincosf = sincos<float32>` will give you a warning, but will work as is.

As I noted in the comments, it should be possible to explicitly provide a type parameter on the definition of `sincos` which would remove the warning.  However, this also requires all of the inferred constraints on that parameter to be specified, which can be a bit ugly.  In this case, the F# compiler unexpectedly rejects the definition anyway:

```
let inline sincos< ^t when ^t : (static member Sin : ^t -> ^t)
                       and ^t : (static member Cos : ^t -> ^t)> (a: ^t) =
  let y = sin a
  let x = cos a
  y, x
```

I believe that this is a compiler bug.

Comment: Is it possible to declare `sincos` with an explicit `'T` type paramter so that the warning goes away?

Comment: What's the reason for that warning anyways?

Comment: @Tim - it _should_ be possible to do that; however, you'd need to explicitly include the constraints as well.  When I try that for this example, the F# compiler becomes unexpectedly unhappy...

Comment: @kvb Right; I can't figure the right syntax for the generic constraints.

Comment: @kvb: Thanks for the answer. Also if I have multiple arguments (e.g. `sincos (a:'T) (b:'T) = ...`) I get warning `FS0686: The method or function 'sincos' should not be given explicit type argument(s) because it does not declare its type parameters explicitly`. Do you think it's possible to remove them with explicit constraints?

Comment: @Stringer Bell - yes, it should probably be possible to remove the warning, but it will depend on the constraints (due to compiler bugs).

Comment: @kvb: I think I know why explicit constraints are not working here: floats and doubles don't actually have static members Sin and Cos.  `sin` and `cos` use the F# compiler only type case statement trick to make calls to System.Math.Sin/Cos overloads as appropriate (see prim-types.fs).

Comment: @Stephen - while it's true that those members are simulated, the failure occurs during the definition of the generic `sincos` method, which doesn't reference any specific types.

Comment: @kvb: ah, right. But I still think this is the underlying cause of the "bug"; the compiler, even though it gives simulated type signatures that make you believe Sin and Cos are just normal static member type constraints, is aware that these are simulated and the static member constraint `^t` given in this explicit constraint doesn't match the simulated static constraint for Sin/Cos.  For example, try replacing `let y...` with `let y = (^T : (static member Sin : ^T -> ^T) (a))` and likewise for `let x...`. The function compiles but with a warning about Sin/Cos being special.

Comment: ... and you can no longer use `sincos` with float/float32, since it apparently knows the difference between simulated and non-simulated Sin/Cos static member type constraints.

Comment: ... well, actually, you can "use" it with float/float32 (it will compile), but it results in a runtime error.

Comment: @Stephen - yes, that seems like a plausible explanation for why the bug exists; unfortunately, simulated members are pretty frequently needed when using `inline` definitions.  In response to my bug report, Don Syme suggested that it might be possible to use signature files to work around the issue.